# How to wrap a very long word

Tags: c#, css

I'm working on a c# web application and in one sections we show user comments on little boxes. It seems that one person wrote a long string causing the box become bigger.

How can I avoid long words to fit its container size?

For example, if the user writes the following

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

and my box has a shorter width

I should make it fit.

Comment: What do you mean by 'make it fit'? Do you want to cut the word in half?

Comment: Maybe I don't get answers for some questions David.

Comment: DouweM, you can see what happens above with my long word, it's affecting the design of the page, I don't want it to happen on my website, because the box is getting over other boxes because of its size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the css property `word-wrap: break-word`. That will force long lines to wrap onto the next one.

Comment: I've seen this and I could make it work on some browsers, but I read not every browser support this property, do you know any other workaround for this to apply to the browsers where this does not work??

Answer (score 4):

A common thing to do is check the character count and replace a long string with a shorter one and an elipsis.

aaaaaa...

and then, if youwant, show the full text in the rollover.

<div title="aaaaaa....aaaa">aaaaa...</div>

In code you can do something like

text = allText.SubString(Min(allText.Length, 80))

And combine this with the CSS styling listed in other answers.

Comment: This can work too, I don't know if the owners of the website will accept this solution though. But thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, thinking better I guess this is not a good option for this case, here is why: let's say you write a normal and common text as "Hello World, I'm writing a comment on stackoverflow", so I could make it read "Hello World, I'm writing...", but if I have a single word, without spacings as "my areas of expertise are: software/hardware/sports/animals/economist/lawyer" and cut it on "hardware" because it's too long for the width of the div. The user will only read one line and that's it...no more description on that box, while in the first example the user will see the box full of text.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use

```
overflow:hidden;
```

These tend to be outliers and usually are mistakes.

[CSS overflow Property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: I can't cut the comment because of the overflow. For example, if I'd write "Hi,howareyoudoingtoday?" and it's wider than its container, I can't put something like "Hi,howareyoudoin", for example.

Comment: How often is that going to happen? Most people will write it as "Hi, how are you doing today?" Which will wrap correctly.

You could also try something like this "overflow-y: hidden;" but it isn't supported by many of the older browsers

Comment: The thing here is that this person wrote areas of expertise separated by "/", but I can't split by that because if someone writes something without it, it will be the same as nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [soft hyphen](http://www.google.com/search?q=soft+hyphen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a). This is a - in most cases - invisible character that breaks a line.